# Bake normals map does not work well

Tags: normals, baking, normal-map

I have issue woth baking normals. In some reason bake does not work well. I tried a lot of ways and configs.. But my normal map is incorect.

When I'm trying to use this generated normal map in Unite or Bldender for low model I see edge of low poly model. In some reason Ray distance does not work for case when low poly sticks out a little.

I'm using Blender 2.81.

Do you have any suggestions how to bake normal map without this issue.

See below screenshots:

High model inside in the low. I generated high model from low by smooth
[image]

Last baking config 
[image]

Tring to use this normal 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should make your low poly model smooth shaded and add at least one bevel in this case.

When blender bakes the normals, it ray casts from the low poly surface inwards along the interpolated normal until it hits the high poly (or not).

If you need the low poly to intersect with the high poly then you can make a copy of the low poly and scale (or shrink/fatten) it up and bake with that. It is also possible to use a Displace modifier to raise the surface a bit during the bake.

[image]

Comment: Hi Jackdaw, Thank you for fast responce. I found tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71sPwqs6C_I that use the same approch that you suggested. And now model looks better - http://prntscr.com/qmc20f But this approach really requires additional preparation of the low model. Do you know maybe in some other 3d editors it (baking) will be work without bevel? And low poly will not need additional bevels.

Comment: I wouldn't expect a much different result from any other software. Marmoset 3 and Substance Painter has some additional features that might help.
The Smooth shaded model above doesn't have any additional bevels and may work as a small detail.